# Why can't I do currentNode = currentNode.Next.Next?

Tags: c#

I have made my own single chained/linked list.
Now, if I want to delete/remove a node/item from my list, I'd have to do something like this:

```
public void Delete(PARAMETERS)
{
    Node previousNode = null, 
        currentNode = f;
    while (currentNode != null)
    {
        if (SOMECONDITION)
        {
            if (previousNode == null)
            {
                f = currentNode.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                previousNode.Next = currentNode.Next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            previousNode = currentNode;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.Next;
    }
}
```

If SOMECONDITION is true, you simply skip the currentNode and therefor effectively "deleting" the node, as nothing points to it anymore.

But, I am really wondering, why can I not do something like this:

```
(...)
        while ()
        {
            if (SOMECONDITION)
            {
                currentNode = currentNode.Next;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.Next;
        }
(...)
```

OR perhaps:

```
(...)
        while ()
        {
            if (SOMECONDITION)
            {
                currentNode = currentNode.Next.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                currentNode = currentNode.Next;
            }
        }
(...)
```

What fundamental understanding do I lack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps if you re-write the original a bit you would see better what you are really doing to the list.

```
public void Delete(PARAMETERS)
{
    var previous = FindPreviousNode(PARAMETERS);
    if( previous == null && Matches(f, PARAMETERS)) {
      f = f.Next;
    } else if(previous != null ) {
      previous.Next = previous.Next.Next;
    } // u could add "else { throw new NodeNotFound() }" if that's appropiate
}
private Node FindPreviousNode(PARAMETERS) {
    Node currentNode = f;
    while (currentNode != null) {
        if (Matches(currentNode.Next, PARAMETERS)) {
            return currentNode;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.Next;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

You have asked around in the comments to understand more what's up with the list and the Next's properties, so here it goes:

Lets say the list is: 1|3|5|7, first points to 1, 1's Next property points to 3, 5's Next points to 7, and 7's Next points to null. That's all you keep track of to store the list. If you set the 5's Next property to null, you are deleting the 7. If instead you set 3's Next property to 7, you are deleting the 5 from the list. If you set first to 3, you are deleting the 1.

Its all about the first and the Next properties. That's what makes the list.

Comment: Ah, that is a good explanation Freddy. Although, I am wondering:
Let us take the 3's property to 7 example.
Why can't I set 3's property to 7 by setting its next to = currentNode.Next.Next?
Why won't this make 3 point at 7?

Comment: If currentNode is 3, and If you know Next is the matching node, setting currentNode.Next = currentNode.Next.Next Will make 3 point to 7. That's precisely what I do in the refactored code I posted in my answer. Its a matter of when / where / in what context you are doing it, and the name you give to the variables ...

Comment: and perhaps I am phrasing myself wrong. Also, why do I NEED previousNode? why do I need that knowledge?
Couldn't you do a If(current.Next == condition) { currentNode.Next = currentNode.Next.Next } or similar?

Comment: y, u can ... that's not what u posted on the modified samples on the question and its probably why many answers were about something different.

Comment: I guess I have handled my question badly.
http://pastebin.com/m7dfbea85
This doesn't work for me at all though, it was the solution I tried in the start and I could not get it to work at all, ever - until I used the previousNode approach instead

Comment: @CasperT y, it doesn't work because of what I am sure is a typo, you are doing "if (previousNode == null)" when you never assigned that. Also as you are only checking if the Next matches, you are not really checking the Head. I really suggest you refactor it, I know I didn't make mine for deleting multiple elements at a time, but I think it will be easier to start from that (which makes it easier to read = less chance for mistake) and add support for the multiple elements. Take what u learned here, and read the original code again carefully ...

Comment: ... I really suggest you handle the head check separately, right until the point where the head isn't matching the condition (or you reached the end of the list). After that, you can use the while you have - without the third if/else, and Always doing currentNode.Next = currentNode.Next.Next; for the matches.

Ps. that code is always assigning the Next of the "removed" element to the Head, so the result was the list without All the elements before the last matching element.

Comment: What do you think of this?
http://pastebin.com/m688a1c98
It seems to work. Thanks for your help. Sorry, but I prefer not to abstract it in this scenario. I definitely understand why it is a good idea though. I'd probably just implement a remove(Node n) instead, if it were :)

Comment: Oh wait, if I enter something like 3,5 and not 3,3 or 1,1 og 7,7 it does not work

Comment: Almost, posted a tiny correction http://pastebin.com/m5644e7ff ... basically, it would have failed with a list with only a single element (or when removing all elements) i.e. there is no Next in that case so you wouldn't be evaluating whether you needed to change the Head. Also the code looks good like that, I suggest defining an InRange method in Node, so you can read pretty well what's is doing: http://pastebin.com/d32527b08

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think of that. Also, your correction does not seem to have solved it all :)
If I enter 5,7 it won't show me 1,3 (e.g blank result)
If I enter 3,5, it only shows me 7

Comment: oops, that's right ... just add an extra check "currentNode == Head" to the first if ... that's why I suggested to separate head from the rest of the code, as its a different logic ... u only want to use current for the head, from then on everything should happen in the .Next - see http://pastebin.com/d7f70104a

Comment: Still doesn't work at all :D now 7 won't be deleted nor 3 if you call the range 3,5

Comment: KNow you know why I have had so much trouble with next.next and just went with previous - although I felt it was too bad.

Comment: Well, I just did a quick look at it ;) ... you have to take a pause and think on what each part is doing, I personally think that trying to make it easier to read helps in that. Missing check here: http://pastebin.com/d534825cf. The code I actually used to spot the issue when looking at it: http://pastebin.com/d46fb76d3. So, I separated the part that erases from the head while it matches. That allowed me to move the if .Next != null to the while. And there was the issue, looking right at me: when you erase the next element, you shouldn't navigate to it - instead go on to check your new Next.

Answer (score 6):

Doing:

```
currentNode = currentNode.Next.Next;
```

Is a prime candidate for a NullReferenceException

EDIT:
Here's a list implementation with some pictures that may help you understand.
http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=176

Comment: But does this mean you can not do it? or don't you just simply need to do a null check in your code then, if you apply the Next.Next practice

Comment: Also, I really could you some more clarification on how to do it properly and some more clarification about previousNode as well

Comment: @CasperT Normally in a linked list your delete method would look something like: Remove(Node nodeToRemove), you seem to be removing a range of nodes?

Comment: True, but why would that change anything?
My "real" code is:
http://pastebin.com/m75cef0a6

Comment: Technically I suppose it wouldn't change anything, but a list is a data-structure and as such should behave the same way regardless of what's stored in it. Personally I'd iterate over the list and then call Remove(Node) on what I want to delete.

Comment: Okay. I'd still really like you to address some of the other things as well though :)
I think I need some better fundamental understand of how all this referencing with .Next and so on works :)

Comment: @dequadin Next.Next isn't synonymous of NullReferenceException ... it depends on the context where its used ...

Comment: @Freddy Rios, I think in the context of the question it is. I can't think of a scenario where you would need to look two nodes ahead in a *unordered* list? And to do so you obviously would need a check that .Next isn't null.

Comment: @CasperT I also added an update in my answer (complete with a quick drawing because I'm bored at work)

Comment: Ok guys, the definite answer is in the comments in my answer. I think it was all due to a bug, and from then on it revealed some misconceptions and pointed the OP in the wrong direction. I don't think there is more to do other than implement ourselves the fix, which I don't think would do any good to the OP - I am certain the OP will be able to do it with all the clarifications I posted there.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to say you can't do Next.Next.

The only issue is what if currentNode.Next is null?  Then you would get an error.

PreviousNode works because you are doing a NULL check before using it.

Comment: Could you show me the implementation? I tried and tried this solution earlier, and I simply could not get it to delete anything

Comment: @Casper the one I posted in my answer does Next.Next ... its safe in the way its done in there, because it does so on the node previous to the target one, so you know the Next node is not null as its the target one ...

Answer (score 2):

currentNode is just a temporary pointer variable (reference) that ceases to exist at the end of the scope (that is by the next closing brace). When you change what that reference points to, you don't change any other references; changing currentNode doesn't magically change what the previous node's Next reference points to.

```
currentNode = currentNode.Next // only changes the temporary reference
```

You have to actually reach into the linked list and change a referende inside the list, which is what you do when you change previousNode.Next - you change what node the previous node considers its next node. You basically tell it "This is your new Next node, forget about the old one".

Also, as the others have stated, you should check for null references throughout. if currentNode.Next is the last node in the list, its Next will point at nothing, and you'll get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: In a linked list you have lots of node objects with a Next reference each. A reference is a variable that "points" at another object. So each object points at its next node, which is why it's called a linked list - the nodes are linked together. Changing one of the Next references makes it point at a new object, which is why previousNode.Next = currentNode.Next skips over currentNode. currentNode itself, however, is just a reference that doesn't reside inside an object node, so changing it has no effect except to change what node you're temporarily looking at.

Comment: I am still not sure why I have to involve previousNode :(

Comment: I don't think I fundamentally grasp how Next is so special and previous and currentnode is not as much

Comment: The Next reference is special because it's inside the Node objects. If it's changed there, it's changed inside that node forever. The new node the Next reference points to is its new successor. The currentNode and previousNode references, however, are just temporary. They are constantly changed to point to other nodes, which doesn't change the internal structure of the list.

Maybe this beautiful drawing clarifies: http://thespug.net/stuff/linkedlist.png (the first list is the initial list, the second after advancing currentNode to node number two, and the third after changing the references)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fully get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you know in both cases that `currentNode.Next` is not null and thus that you can apply `.Next` on it? You are only checking for the `!= null` in the loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

The assignments to currentNode and previousNode do not alter the structure of the linked list.  They're merely used to step through the structure.

The assignment to previousNode.Next is what changes the structure.  Doing currentNode = currentNode.Next.Next will skip over the next node (if currentNode.Next is not null) but it won't alter the structure of the list.

Comment: But WHY does previousNode.Next change the structure?

Comment: Assigning to previousNode.Next (or currentNode.Next) changes the structure because it changes the Next property in the node referred to by the variable.  Assigning to previousNode or CurrentNode directly just changes the reference without changing the object itself.

Comment: Egh, I feel stupid for repeating myself. There is clearly something fundamental I am not getting. Why can previous.next change the structure of my list? Currentnode points at f, but previous starts pointing at previous. Changing previous's values should not effect Currentnode or the list :-s e.g I have been looking at this all day and I keep confusing myself more and more

Comment: and that confuses me once again, why I can not just do currentNode = currentNode.Next.Next and thereby doing a skip

Comment: Because the value of currentNode changes every time you go through the loop, to point to the next node in the list. In the first code snippet you use "currentNode = currentNode.Next" to just advance in the list as the last thing you do in the while loop, but you're wondering why you can't use the exact same expression to do something else entirely...

Answer (score 0):

You should really sketch a picture of the linked list if you're wondering about problems like this. It's far easier to *see* what needs to be done to accomplish some linked list mutation, than it is to reason it out.

Comment: Could you show an example of an illustration? I am having a hard time seeing how I could sketch it.
Forexample if the list has the values: 1|7|3|9 and I want to remove the node that contains the data: 9

Comment: @CaspetT you remove it by setting the node 3's Next property to null. Which means there is no node after that element, so that's the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't follow the posted code at all.

If this is a standard linked list (each node has a Next, but that's it), follow these steps to run a deletion of a single item:

Step 1: Find the target node you want to delete, but keep track of the previous node visited.
Step 2: prevNode.Next = targetNode.Next

Note: special checks for deleting the head of the list need to be done.